# C ++ Boost: ошибка при попытке импорта

Tags: c++, linux, boost

При попытке запустить вот такой вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "test";
    return 0;
}
```

При попытке компиляции вот таким образом: g++ findData.cpp - я получаю ошибку

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccuF9xWj.o: в функции «__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)»:
findDataAboutDirLinux.cpp:(.text+0x6d): неопределённая ссылка на «boost::system::generic_category()»
/usr/bin/ld: findDataAboutDirLinux.cpp:(.text+0x79): неопределённая ссылка на «boost::system::generic_category()»
/usr/bin/ld: findDataAboutDirLinux.cpp:(.text+0x85): неопределённая ссылка на «boost::system::system_category()»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Погуглив, я попробовал указать пути к библиотеке через -l и -L руками, это ничем не помогло.

Во всех случаях итог один.
Есть идеи, что делать?
У меня ubuntu 20.04.03, компилятор g++ и vs code

Я пробовал гуглить статьи на эту тему, но не нашел ничего такого, что могло бы мне помочь. Кто-то писал про изменение файла make, помогите пожалуйста и скажите, где и как именно его менять.

Comment: Не прилинковали boost-system?

Comment: Простите, а как это сделать?) Я просто новичок в этом деле, поэтому много не догоняю(

Comment: По идее, `-lboost_system`.

Comment: Первым делом попробовал это, не сработало (ошибка идентична той, что уже указана выше)

Comment: Флаг писали справа от имени файла с кодом или слева? Нужно справа.

Comment: Справа, команда выглядела так: g++ findData.cpp -lboost_system

Comment: Чего-то вы недоговариваете... У меня вообще без флагов собирается. Версия линукса та же.

Comment: Если честно - понятия не имею, в чем дело...

Comment: Пожалуйста, вместо общих фраз: _Дубликат вопроса не помог решить проблему_, добавте в вопрос больше конкретики, почему ответы там не помогли?

Comment: Вот вы сказали, что `-lboost_system` не помог. Ошибка осталась та же, дословно?

Comment: Верно, ошибка все та же

Comment: С командой `g++ findData.cpp -lboost_system` ошибка вообще не может быть, как в вопросе, потому что в тексте ошибки упоминается другой файл `findDataAboutDirLinux.cpp`. *"Кто-то писал про изменение файла make, помогите пожалуйста и скажите, где и как именно его менять."* - в вопросе ничего не упоминается про make файл. Не вводите читающих в заблуждение и приводите настоящие подробности.

Comment: извиняюсь, просто опечатка вышла, но суть это не меняет, там все идентично

Comment: ¿Ну так а сборка все-таки через make файл делается?